# failed to resolve patches for `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`

Tags: rust, libc, rust-cargo

I'm trying to build rust with libc(from my local machine) where I made some changes. But I'm facing this issue. Please help

```
  error: failed to resolve patches for `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`

Caused by:
  patch for `libc` in `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index` did not resolve to any crates. If this is unexpected, you may wish to consult: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/4678
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./x.py", line 11, in <module>
    bootstrap.main()
  File "/local/mnt/workspace/mahto/rust/src/bootstrap/bootstrap.py", line 960, in main
    bootstrap(help_triggered)
  File "/local/mnt/workspace/mahto/rust/src/bootstrap/bootstrap.py", line 929, in bootstrap
    build.build_bootstrap()
  File "/local/mnt/workspace/mahto/rust/src/bootstrap/bootstrap.py", line 724, in build_bootstrap
    run(args, env=env, verbose=self.verbose)
  File "/local/mnt/workspace/mahto/rust/src/bootstrap/bootstrap.py", line 143, in run
    raise RuntimeError(err)
RuntimeError: failed to run: /local/mnt/workspace/mahto/rust/build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/stage0/bin/cargo build --manifest-path /local/mnt/workspace/mahto/rust/src/bootstrap/Cargo.toml --verbose
```

This is my `Cargo.toml`:

```
[patch."https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo"]
cargo = { path = "src/tools/cargo" }

[patch.crates-io]
# Similar to Cargo above we want the RLS to use a vendored version of `rustfmt`
# that we're shipping as well (to ensure that the rustfmt in RLS and the
# `rustfmt` executable are the same exact version).
rustfmt-nightly = { path = "src/tools/rustfmt" }

# See comments in `src/tools/rustc-workspace-hack/README.md` for what's going on
# here
rustc-workspace-hack = { path = 'src/tools/rustc-workspace-hack' }

# See comments in `tools/rustc-std-workspace-core/README.md` for what's going on
# here
rustc-std-workspace-core = { path = 'src/tools/rustc-std-workspace-core' }
rustc-std-workspace-alloc = { path = 'src/tools/rustc-std-workspace-alloc' }
rustc-std-workspace-std = { path = 'src/tools/rustc-std-workspace-std' }
libc = { path = '../libc'}
```

this is my `cargo.lock`:

```
[[package]]
name = "libc"
version = "0.2.70"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "3baa92041a6fec78c687fa0cc2b3fae8884f743d672cf551bed1d6dac6988d0f"
dependencies = [
 "rustc-std-workspace-core",
]
```

my libc version is v0.2.70, and libc directory is just outside the rust directory and (`path = "../libc"`)

Comment: It is hard to answer this kind of question because you are doing something barely everyone ever does (patching crates), so you are unlikely to attract answers from people who just happen to know how to solve this issue, and have not included a way for us to reproduce your issue, so you are unlikely to attract answers from people willing to try and test for you.

Comment: @mcarton I understand. But is there a way for this to get resolved? someone whom I can contact and have done this. Any help would be nice.

Comment: @mcarton The facts that a lot of Rust crates are opensource and the ecosystem is young (read: crates are missing a lot of features), I find that statement hard to agree.